# Show custom pop-up on back/forward button press of browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a special requirement.
I have a web page and when user press back button of the browser on the page, 
it should show a pop –up message.
I tried the codes below but it is not working

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {

    $.fancybox({
        content: "<b>some text</B>",
        padding: 0,
        centerOnScroll: true,
        overlayColor: "#000",
        overlayOpacity: .7
    });
};
```

This pop up is shown for a moment and taken to the back page itself.
My intension is to show  a  **custom pop-up with 2 buttons** and on clicking
on one of the button it should NOT GO the back page
and clicking on the other should go to the back page

is it possible to show such custom pop ups with custom actions?

Comment: here's some info on the onbeforeunload event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is simple answer: you cannot!

`window.onbeforeunload` only can return `string`! BTW firefox doesn't allow customized message.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
    return "My message which make users not so happy!";
}
```

If you want some kind of hacky workaround to make your users never come back to your site, you could see that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16824414/1414562