# beforeunload event has two events (stay on page) and (leave the page) is there any way to determine the events id or class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

hi all i am working with `beforeunload` jquery event but i am a bit confuse because i am in situation like if user click on `leave the page` button than i have to call `ajax` and delete the data i saved. if user click on stay on page button i wont send an `ajax` request than. but the problem is that i did'nt find any thing that can complete my problem in stack overflow as well as in Google.
i have copied this snippet which is working perfectly

```
 $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
            return 'my pharse!';
    });
```

But what i want to do is:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
         if(click on leave the page button)
         {
            ajax({ url:'',method;'post' }); etc
         }
         else
         {
            do nothing;
         }
return 'my pharse ';            
    });
```

Comment: The **[answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16824414/2065039)** might help you..

Comment: quite helpful but still i am not cleared on it

Comment: what is not clear to you??

Comment: how can i catch these both botton events which appears in confirm box

Comment: I think that isn't possible!! See **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5259246/2065039)**

Comment: but i need to catch this button leave the page

Comment: Its quite **not possible** buddy!! Check **[this link too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7080331/2065039)**

Comment: any alternative approach

Comment: I don't think you have one!! Not sure though..

Comment: hmmm so it means i am stuck fully stuck i have to re-structure the whole page and other stuff with different approach