# using onbeforeunload event, url change on 'Leave Page'

Tags: browser-cache

I am having a requirement that when a user makes his payment and reached on success page and go back it should be redirected to a custom page. So if i will click on browser back button it will show me two options - Leave Page and Stay on this page. When i will click on Leave page it should redirect to my custom page. I found following link useful but not working for 'Leave Page' button....kindly suggest or help.

[using onbeforeunload event, url change on selecting stay on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695886/using-onbeforeunload-event-url-change-on-selecting-stay-on-this-page/16824414?noredirect=1#comment50417306_16824414)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? It would be really grateful if you could provide some help! :)